# How to change the HTML elements dynamically in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

I have a group of radio buttons on my page:

```
<form ...>
   <input type="radio" name="people" checked> Student
   <input type="radio" name="people"> Teacher
   <input type="radio" name="people"> Assistant

   <!-- Here is the dynamic content, which could be check boxes or radio buttons-->
</form>
```

The feature I would like to implement is:

- Based on the selection of the radio buttons, the **content** after the radio buttons will change **dynamically**. (The radio buttons and the content are inside a form.)

For example:

1. If "**student**" is selected, the dynamic content part is (check boxes):

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="name" /> Name <br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="Age" /> Age <br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="grade" /> Grade <br />
   ```
2. If "**Teacher**" is selected, the dynamic content part is (check boxes & radio buttons):

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="subject" /> Subject <br />

   <input type="radio" name="code" checked> 111
   <input type="radio" name="code"> 222
   <input type="radio" name="code"> 333
   ```
3. If "**Assistant**" is selected, the dynamic content part is other check boxes.

How to implement this **dynamic content change** in **jQuery**?

---

### What I tried

I tried to create HTML elements dynamically in Javascript, but I feel it is not a good way since I have to write HTML elements in Javascript as strings.

Comment: You could just show and hide the various elements with CSS. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to create HTML elements dynamically in Javascript, but I feel it is not a good way since I have to write HTML in Javascript as strings

Answer (score 6):

Try this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QX4fS/)**

**Markup change**

```
<form ...>
   <input type="radio" name="people" value="student" checked> Student
   <input type="radio" name="people" value="teacher"> Teacher
   <input type="radio" name="people" value="assistant"> Assistant

   <div class="content student">
     <input type="checkbox" name="name" /> Name <br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="Age" /> Age <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="grade" /> Grade <br />
   </div>

   <div class="content teacher" style="display:none;">
      Teacher content
   </div>

   <div class="content assistant" style="display:none;">
      Assistant content
   </div>
</form>
```

**Js**

```
$(function(){

   $("input[name=people]").click(function(){
      $("div.content").not("."+this.value).hide();
      $("."+this.value).show();
   });

});
```

Comment: @Leem - Did you take a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

put all three possible elements in your static html and wrap each part with a div. Then Show and hide the divs on click

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...  I would create different divs that are hidden that contain the combinations that you are looking for.  Then on the onclick of the radio button I would hide divs that you don't want shown and show the divs that you are looking for.